# javascript outputs weird characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I've built an application and it worked just fine until today.
When I checked it today, all of the hebrew characters turned to something like `×˜×§×¡×˜`. I've tried adding `charset="UTF-8"` to all of my script files (when including them) but it just doesn't work. The first statement in my HTML markup is the

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

I have to mention that it happens only when the output is coming from JS or CSS file. I fixed the CSS problem by adding `@charset="UTF-8"`  to the top of the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: The .js file itself has to be saved in UTF-8 encoded. Check the coding of the saved file.

Comment: @Teemu well, it worked up until today. all of a sudden it stopped working, but yea, i opened the file in notepad and saved it as UTF-8 and the problem was solved. That's weird that it actually worked up until today then..

Comment: You (or someone else) have accidentally saved the file using other encoding?

Comment: well, my IDE is saving it as UTF-8 as default. Guess there was a bug

Comment: What headers does your server send?

Comment: @Bergi lot of them? Not sure I understand what you are asking. When the server is requesting the page it has 8 request headers and 7 response headers

Comment: I mean the character-encoding header of the response, sorry for being unspecific

Comment: @Bergi there is no `character-encoding` however, there is `transfer-encoding` which is `chunked`

Comment: To be very specific, the `Content-Type` header field :-) It should contain a `charset` after the mime type.

Comment: @Bergi it only says `text/html`

Comment: It should be `text/javascript; charset=utf-8` I guess… If the "wrong" characters come from JS or CSS files, the encoding of the HTML is not important. The script itself needs to be served correctly.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, I was looking at the HTML/PHP file that's being requested. When looking at the JS files, there is no `Content-Type` in the response headers none request header

Comment: Hm, there *should* be… Configure your server to send one.

Comment: @Bergi how do I configure my server to send one?

Comment: Depends on what server you use. It's one of the basic features of a server though, so check the docs